# Representations of a certain algebra

Tags: matrices, reference-request, representation-theory

I'm interested in the $F$-algebra
$$F[x_1, \dots, x_n]/(x_1^2, \dots, x_n^2).$$
and its representations. Is there a name for this algebra?

I was led to this while searching for commuting matrices $A_1, \dots, A_n$ such that 
$A_i^2 = 0$
for each $i$, and
$$A_1 A_2 \cdots A_n \neq 0.$$
It's easy to find such matrices of size $2^n$ by considering the matrices of $x_1, \dots, x_n$ in the regular representation of the above algebra, but I would like to find smaller matrices, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $F$ is a field, I think that should be the smallest example.

If $A_1A_2 \dots A_n \ne 0$ then there is there is some vector $\vec{v}$ such that $A_1A_2 \dots A_n\vec{v} \ne 0$.  Now for each subset $S \subset \{1,\dots,n\}$ consider the vectors $\vec{v}_S = (\prod_{s \in S}A_s)\vec{v}$, with $\vec{v}_\emptyset = \vec{v}$. Note that none of these can be zero since $A_1A_2 \dots A_n\vec{v} \ne 0$, but in fact I claim these are linearly independent.

If not, suppose we have some linear relation $\sum c_S\vec{v}_S = 0$ with not all of the coefficients $c_S$ being zero. Choose $S$ minimal (by containment) such that $c_S \ne 0$, and let's hit this by the operator $A_{S^c}$ where $S^c$ is the complement of $S$ in $\{1,\dots,n\}$. The equation then becomes $c_S A_1A_2\dots A_n \vec{v} = 0$, which implies $A_1A_2\dots A_n \vec{v} = 0$ (since I assumed we are working over a field) as $c_S \ne 0$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Let $M$ be a finite-dimensional $A$-module such that the subspace $x_1\cdots x_nM$ is not zero and let $m$ be a nonzero vector there, equal to $x_1\cdots x_mr$ for some $r\in M$. The unique morphism $f:A\to M$ of $A$-modules which maps $1$ to $r$ is injective, because its restriction to the socle of $A$ is injective.

Comment: You can produce many other examples of algebras with the same property using Macaulay's method of inverse systems -— this is explained in Eisenbud and Harris's book on commutative algebra, for example.

Comment: I assume you mean Eisenbud's "Commutative Algebra with a view..."; this is interesting, since my first approach to this was to use the ring of differential operators on $n$ variables, mod the ideal vanishing at the polynomial $y_1 \cdots y_n$, and they mention this as an example in the exercises. Thanks!

Comment: Moreover, since A is a self injective algebra, the map f that I described is split, that is, its image is a direct summands of M. This means that the matrices you got from the regular representation and direct sum of them are essentially the only ones there are.